# Centered image with text

Tags: html, sql, css, wordpress

I'm using Wordpress for a backend. I pretty much had to try to strip everything from the layout.

Do you know if theres a way to have a plain html text file without having to create a template in wordpress?

I'm having trouble centering some text including an image, I was wondering if someone could help me out.

http://spiketradinginc.com

It is misaligned with wider browsers/different resolutions.

Comment: Since you are new here, accept the answer(tick) which solved your problem. Up-vote(up arrow) the answer(s) which give(s) you information or help(s) you. Down-vote(down arrow) the answer(s) which are fake.

Answer (score 0):

change the styles in your css

```
#newsticker 
{
width: 600px;
margin: 0 auto;
}



 #newsticker img 
{
margin: 0 auto;
width: 600px;
}

#header 
{
margin: 0 auto;
width: 420px;
}
```

Comment: That code you gave me helped me out. I appreciate it. I bought the domain name for a friend of mine and me. He lives in indian rocks beach, florida. And I'm setting up to launch a online investment company. I got a friend that does a lot of php programming something similar to this website - http://www.derwentcapitalmarkets.com

Comment: @BlakeTallos : ur welcome and if my answer helped you to solve the issue accept it as answer. Then only the question will get closed also

Answer (score 0):

> Do you know if theres a way to have a plain html text file without
>   having to create a template in wordpress?

WordPress first determines whether it has a [static front page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page). If a static front page has been set, then WordPress loads that page according to the [page template hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Page_display).

If a static front page has not been set, then WordPress looks for a template file called `home.php` and uses it to generate the requested page.

If `home.php` is missing, WordPress looks for a file called `index.php` in the active theme's directory, and uses that template to generate the page.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the option of "Page Template" for the blank page also the css you have used has the problem in it to center align anything you can use a (Div Tag with Margin:auto and width:400px (Less then page width))

```
    <div style="margin:auto;width:400px">ANy image or text</div>
```